# Python Data Types: What does '|S...' Mean?

Tags: python, numpy

A noob question, but in this numpy array:

```
array(['22', '38', '26', '35', '35', '', '54', '2', '27', '14', '4', '58',    '20', '39', '14'], dtype='|S82')
```

what does '|S82' mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) it defines the byte-order, kind, and size of the datatype. In this case:

```
byte-order: |   not applicable
kind:       S   (byte-)string
size:       82  (characters long)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
In [292]: np.array(['one', 'two','three']) # a
Out[292]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='<S5')
```

for efficiency, numpy align data. Here, all items are string of at most 5 caracters, for hosting the initial `'three'`.

```
In [295]: a[1]='seventeen';a
Out[295]: array(['one', 'seven', 'three'], dtype='<S5')
```

You can't furthermore have longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

From the [NumPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) the first letter of the dtype tells you what kind of data it is.

```
Array-protocol type strings (see The Array Interface) 

The first character specifies the kind of data and the remaining characters
specify the number of bytes per item, except for Unicode, where it is     
interpreted as the number of characters. The item size must correspond to an    
existing type, or an error will be raised. The supported kinds are  
  'b'       boolean  
  'i'       (signed) integer   
  'u'       unsigned integer  
  'f'       floating-point  
  'c'       complex-floating point  
  'O'       (Python) objects  
  'S', 'a'  (byte-)string  
  'U'       Unicode  
  'V'       raw data (void)
```

So in your example it is designating that is it a byte-string that is 82 characters long.